# DateField display correct on simulator but not correct on device

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I save the time of DateField with string such as:

```
String time =  "8 March 2012 05:44:00".
```

I user HTTP to parse.

```
 Date date = new Date( HttpDateParser.parse(time) );

 DateField dateField = new DateField();
 dateField.setDate(date);
```

And this dateField display correct "8 March 2012 05:44" on simulator but on device is "1970" instead "2012".

I try to use

```
 Date date = new Date( HttpDateParser.parse(time)*1000L );
```

and

```
Date date = new Date( HttpDateParser.parse(time)*60*1000L );
```

but result is also not correct on simulator and device.

Anyboydy can help me solve this problem plz ?

Answer (score 1):

Your time string is not one of the formats supported by [HttpDateParser](http://file:///G:/Program%20Files%20%28x86%29/Research%20In%20Motion/BlackBerry%20JDE%207.1.0/docs/api/net/rim/device/api/io/http/HttpDateParser.html). I have read where people have had luck pre-pending a weekday (it doesn't matter which one) to the string. Try:

```
Date date = new Date( HttpDateParser.parse( "Mon, "+ time));
```